# index required for firestore fields to use orderBy in query

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I was building a simple query that includes ordering at the end.

But firestore is asking me to create index that combines the queried field and the `orderBy` field. And it is going to be many indexes that will be created for this that combine the order field with the rest fields (or even combination of fields).

I have 4 fields to filter results by, and need to be ordered by another field for which I have to create 24 indexes for the different combinations, including both ascending and descending for order. This way if I have tens of fields? I think I am going to have to create hundreds of indexes.

So is it a good practice to get on and create all those numerous indexes of combination of fields combined with the order by field, even for both directions `ASC` and `DESC`? would it create issues if I proceed with that? or what pattern is fit for this simple task way to do this?

My query is

```
var query = ref.collection("data/devices");

if (params.region) query = query.where("region", "==", params.region);
if (params.color) query = query.where("color", "==", params.color);
query = query.orderBy("price", "ASC ");
```

in my test, only `params.color` wasn't included since it was undefined. So the query only had `.where("region")` and orderBy price

And it generated this error `Error: 9 FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index. You can create it here: [Link to create the index]`

Comment: There is very little generic advice we can give, beyond what is already in the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview  Rather than telling us that your query is simple, edit your question to show exactly what queries you will run. In addition, I recommend reading my explanation of how Firestore uses indexes here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68217144/how-is-the-order-of-the-fields-in-firestore-composite-indexes-decided/68217368#68217368

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you for the resources. I have also edited to add the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To handle the query you're showing:

```js
var query = ref.collection("data/devices");

if (params.region) query = query.where("region", "==", params.region);
if (params.color) query = query.where("color", "==", params.color);
query = query.orderBy("price", "ASC");
```

You need to create 2 composite indexes:

- region ASC, price ASC
- color ASC, price ASC

Those 2 separate indexes will be merged and will be able to handle the combination you need, even when using both `region` and/or `color`. For example:

```js
db.collection('whatever')
  .where('region', '==', 'A')
  .where('color', '==', 'B')
  .where('prop3', '==', 'C')
  .where('prop4', '==', 'D')
  .orderBy('price', 'ASC');
```

If that query is exactly what you will always use, you can create a single composite index with the 5 fields. But, if the "where" clauses are optional, then you'd need to create 4 different composite indexes:

- region ASC, price ASC
- color ASC, price ASC
- prop3 ASC, price ASC
- prop4 ASC, price ASC

You also get the benefit of having different combinations available, like:

```js
.where('region', '==', 'A').where('prop4', '==', 'D').orderBy('price', 'ASC');
```

for example.

This is called *Index Merging* and is well explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#taking_advantage_of_index_merging).

**Edit:**
Notice that:

- Index merging only works with equality comparisons (`.where('x', '==', 5)`) and not range comparisons (`.where('x', '<', 5)`).
- If you want to sort by `price,DESC` instead of `ASC` you will have to create a different set of indexes as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#queries_supported_by_composite_indexes).